# Node.js / Axios won't connect to localhost

Tags: node.js, http, proxy, axios

I have a cryptocurrency (Nano) node running locally on my computer. It has an RPC API and I've tested that I can successfully make calls to it using curl. E.g.

`curl -d '{ "action": "account_balance", "account": "xrb_1aaprwcu9fac1tw3wesud5txb1zuiroti5xfr19bwozitjnnmbcbwpr1w95f" }' localhost:7076`

However I'm trying to do the same thing in a node script and keep getting `ECONNREFUSED`

Here's my node script (the important parts).

```
const axios = require('axios')
const config = require('./config')

const rpc = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'localhost:7076', // I've also tried 'http://localhost:7076'
  // I've tried with and without proxy settings, I don't understand proxies very well though
  /*proxy: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 7077
  }*/
})

function createAddress(accountIndex) {
  // Ensure accountIndex is a string
  accountIndex = accountIndex + ''
  // Get a new private key
  return rpc.post('/', {
    action: 'deterministic_key',
    index: accountIndex,
    seed: config.walletSeed
  })
    // Add to the local wallet
    .then(function(result){
      return rpc.post('/', {
        action: 'wallet_add',
        key: result.private,
        wallet: config.walletId
      })
    })
    // Return the account address
    .then(function(result){
      return result.account
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Error', err)
    })
}

createAddress(52).then(function(address){
  console.log(address)
})
```

And here's the error.

```
Error { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7076
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1170:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 7076,
  config:
   { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     timeout: 0,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.18.0',
        'Content-Length': 117 },
     method: 'post',
     baseURL: 'http://localhost:7076',
     url: 'http://localhost:7076/',
     data: '{"action":"deterministic_key","index":"52","seed":"***"}' },
  request:
   Writable {
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     _events:
      { response: [Function: handleResponse],
        error: [Function: handleRequestError] },
     _eventsCount: 2,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _options:
      { protocol: 'http:',
        maxRedirects: 21,
        maxBodyLength: 10485760,
        path: '/',
        method: 'post',
        headers: [Object],
        agent: undefined,
        auth: undefined,
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: '7076',
        nativeProtocols: [Object],
        pathname: '/' },
     _redirectCount: 0,
     _requestBodyLength: 117,
     _requestBodyBuffers: [ [Object] ],
     _onNativeResponse: [Function],
     _currentRequest:
      ClientRequest {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Socket],
        connection: [Socket],
        _header: 'POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.18.0\r\nContent-Length: 117\r\nHost: localhost:7076\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Agent],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/',
        _ended: false,
        res: null,
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _redirectable: [Circular],
        [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     _currentUrl: 'http://localhost:7076/' },
  response: undefined }
```

I feel like I've tried countless variations of configuration. What am I not getting?

Comment: In my case using `http://localhost:8080` instead of `localhost:8080` did the trick. Thanks giving me the idea.

Answer (score 9):

This is 4 months later but I've been trying to figure out the same thing.

Try changing your instance configuration like this:

```
  const rpc = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'localhost:7076', 
    proxy: false  
})
```

I couldn't find the solution so I ended up digging through axios' code.

I found this on line 89 of /lib/adapters/http.js:

```
var proxy = config.proxy;
if (!proxy && proxy !== false) {
  var proxyEnv = protocol.slice(0, -1) + '_proxy';
  var proxyUrl = process.env[proxyEnv] || process.env[proxyEnv.toUpperCase()];
  if (proxyUrl) {
    var parsedProxyUrl = url.parse(proxyUrl);
    proxy = {
      host: parsedProxyUrl.hostname,
      port: parsedProxyUrl.port
    };

    if (parsedProxyUrl.auth) {
      var proxyUrlAuth = parsedProxyUrl.auth.split(':');
      proxy.auth = {
        username: proxyUrlAuth[0],
        password: proxyUrlAuth[1]
      };
    }
  }
}

if (proxy) {
  options.hostname = proxy.host;
  options.host = proxy.host;
  options.headers.host = parsed.hostname + (parsed.port ? ':' + parsed.port : '');
  options.port = proxy.port;
  options.path = protocol + '//' + parsed.hostname + (parsed.port ? ':' + parsed.port : '') + options.path;...
```

The way I read it, if there is no proxy entry in your config or if your proxy entry is not false (the boolean). Then it makes the var 'proxy' equal to it's default proxy. So when it gets down to line 110...

```
if (proxy) {...
```

...there is a proxy, (the default it just created) and it will use it.

When I added **proxy: false** to my config axios worked as I expected.

Comment: Worked for me as I'm behind a corporate proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to use your direct IP?
Type in your terminal:

> netstat

192.168.1.?

Failing this simple answer/explaination, I set-up a Docker VM on my local machine and connect to my personal RPC API via this:

https://hub.docker.com/r/jlmconsulting/upcoind/

Comment: updated with my ip address, still unable to hit localhost node

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, trying to make a request from a nodejs express app on port 8001 to another Nodejs express app running on port 8000 on my machine. What worked for me was to write the request address like so:

```
const testRequest = async () => {
    try {
    const test = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/test'); 
   //rather than just localhost:8000/test
    console.log('TEST', test);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('TEST ERROR:', e);
  }
};
```

and it worked. I've seen in your comments that you've tried the same using the config, so I find it strange that it did not work...

Answer (score 0):

I solves this by adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin extension on my browser.